# SUBSTRING with Condition

Tags: sql-server, substring, conditional-statements

I would like to have this +3 apply when the paymentterm if is less than 45.

My current code is:

```
SELECT 
    [course_title],
    sblPOAmount,
    SBLInvoiceDate,
    paymentTerm,
    DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) 
FROM 
    [A_Sys].[dbo].[Eventtbl]
WHERE 
    DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) = 'June' 
    AND DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) = '2017'
```

#

WITH SUM Statement (Summary)

```
SELECT
SUM(sblPOAmount) AS totalPOAmt,
case 
    when paymentTerm = '45 Days'
    then DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) 
    else DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 0, SBLInvoiceDate))
end 
FROM 
[A_Sys].[dbo].[Eventtbl] 
WHERE DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(day,SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2)+3,SBLInvoiceDate))='June' 
AND DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(day,SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2)+3,SBLInvoiceDate))='2017'
Group By paymentTerm,SBLInvoiceDate
```

#

Currently, i am not able to sum due to the group by

#

Current Output:
+-----+---+
|10.60| 23|
|0.00 |24 |
|10.50|14 |
+---------+

#

Expected output:
just 21.10

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: please post sample data and expected output

Comment: microsoft sql server.. @NigelFds

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a case statement...

```
SELECT 
    [course_title],
    sblPOAmount,
    SBLInvoiceDate,
    paymentTerm,
    case 
        when paymentTerm < 45 then DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) 
        else DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2), SBLInvoiceDate))
    end
FROM 
    [A_Sys].[dbo].[Eventtbl]
WHERE 
    DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) = 'June' 
    AND DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) = '2017'
```

**Based on the edit**

```
SELECT 
    [course_title],
    sum(sblPOAmount),
    SBLInvoiceDate,
    paymentTerm,
    case 
        when paymentTerm < 45 then DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) 
        else DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2), SBLInvoiceDate))
    end
FROM 
    [A_Sys].[dbo].[Eventtbl]
WHERE 
    DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) = 'June' 
    AND DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) = '2017'
GROUP BY
    [course_title],
    SBLInvoiceDate,
    paymentTerm,
    case 
        when paymentTerm < 45 then DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2) + 3, SBLInvoiceDate)) 
        else DATENAME(Day, DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(paymentTerm, 1, 2), SBLInvoiceDate))
    end
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i am looking! i still have some problem, i can't sum the value of sblPOAmount. i think i will revise my question

Comment: @kelvinfoo i'm not sure what you mean, but I've provided a revision to my answer that may work for you

Comment: Hi simon.. what i mean is to sum the result together. currently output i will update in the question..